# Android USB host-to-serial connection?

Tags: android, usb, arduino

Apparently with Android 2.3.4 and 3.1 one can now access USB accessories.

I have a Ardupilot Mega (based on Arduino) board with a USB cable connected to my laptop, and I can connect to it using a simple serial communications program over COM7 and 115,200 baud. This allows me into the command-line interface, and I can issue commands and get logs.

Is it possible to write an Android app that will communicate over USB to my Ardupilot Mega board?

I've seen many similar threads, but most of them were pre-USB host.

Comment: I've found https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver and its successor https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary which is specifically built for arduinos.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial

Comment: @Bergi , github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial .. this example is very good, thanks, I tried with same example i'm not getting correct values in EditText, what BOARD is sending via USB, can you tell me reason.

Comment: @kgsharathkumar No I can't. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide details, code, and output.

Comment: @Bergi , Okay no problem... i will try , thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**[usb-serial-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/)** is my open source library written for exactly this need.  It supports FTDI and CDC-ACM usb serial devices using Android's USB host support; no root or ADK necessary. It can talk most Arduinos.

The project is still in its early days, but the basic support has worked well enough for several projects.  There is also a [discussion list](http://groups.google.com/group/usb-serial-for-android) where you can get help.

Comment: Is there any source code example that works with CDC/ACM devices?

Comment: Unfortunately, the LGPL license makes it unusuable for most projects.

Comment: this is the one i was looking for. Thanks a ton. However i have a question. Can it send files too?

Comment: It's March 2023 now, and this library is well supported and up-to-date!

Comment: @Michael thanks! the maintainer (no longer me) has been awesome at keeping it well-supported.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the library from [mik3y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371178/2207083) (see here: [**mik3y/usb-serial-for-android**](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)) seems to be long dead. It has many problems and waiting pull requests. Also the LGPL licence prevents anybody to fork it and maintain it.

But don't lose your hope, there's a working replacement and it's under the MIT licence. [**felHR85/UsbSerial**](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial#devices-supported).

**EDIT:** I found a maintained fork of mik3y's library. But the licence or readme is not updated, so I suppose the owner doesn't have a connection to mik3y and simply took it and improved it. I hope he won't get into any trouble because of the licence, because we need this library. See [kai-morich/usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/kai-morich/usb-serial-for-android)

**EDIT2:** It seems that all of these libraries are maintained again, mik3y joined forces with kai-morich and they're working together now.

**EDIT3:** [**mik3y/usb-serial-for-android**](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) is under MIT license now. And still maintained in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  Check out the [Android Open Accessories announcement on the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html).  The Arduino Mega ADK is compatible.  Not sure about the Ardupilot Mega.

From their page:

> The Android 3.1 platform (also backported to Android 2.3.4) introduces
>   Android Open Accessory support, which allows external USB hardware (an
>   Android USB accessory) to interact with an Android-powered device in a
>   special "accessory" mode. When an Android-powered powered device is in
>   accessory mode, the connected accessory acts as the USB host (powers
>   the bus and enumerates devices) and the Android-powered device acts as
>   the USB device. Android USB accessories are specifically designed to
>   attach to Android-powered devices and adhere to a simple protocol
>   (Android accessory protocol) that allows them to detect
>   Android-powered devices that support accessory mode. Accessories must
>   also provide 500mA at 5V for charging power. Many previously released
>   Android-powered devices are only capable of acting as a USB device and
>   cannot initiate connections with external USB devices. Android Open
>   Accessory support overcomes this limitation and allows you to build
>   accessories that can interact with an assortment of Android-powered
>   devices by allowing the accessory to initiate the connection.
>
> Note: Accessory mode is ultimately dependent on the device's hardware
>   and not all devices will support accessory mode. Devices that support
>   accessory mode can be filtered using a "uses-feature" element in your
>   corresponding application's Android manifest. For more information,
>   see the USB Accessory Developer Guide.
>
> The following list of distributers are currently producing Android
>   Open Accessory compatible development boards:
>
> **The Arduino Store provides the Arduino Mega ADK (in EU nations or
>   non-EU nations) that is based on the ATmega2560 and supports the ADK
>   firmware.**  DIY Drones provides an Arduino-compatible board geared
>   towards RC (radio controlled) and UAV (unmanned aerial vehicle)
>   enthusiasts. Microchip provides a PIC based USB microcontroller board.
>   Modern Device provides an Arduino-compatible board that supports the
>   ADK firmware. RT Corp provides an Arduino-compatible board based on
>   the Android ADK board design. Seeed Studio provides an
>   Arduino-compatible board that supports the ADK firmware. SparkFun's
>   IOIO board now has beta support for the ADK firmware.

Comment: Yes ssaw that but that turns the android device into a usb accesory,and the Arduino board needs to play host,requiring an adapter etc.. I'm sure there is an easy way just to get the serials comms up in usb host mode.

Answer (score -2):

You can check out the library described in *[Slick USB 2 Serial Library](http://slickdevlabs.com/slick-usb-2-serial-library/)*.

It enables common USB-to-serial adapters to work with Android devices that have USB host mode without needing to root.

Comment: the link posted is broken.

Answer (score -2):

http://slickdevlabs.com/

I am currently using the library in my own app, however I think you can get away with just the app that slick has on the market. There are two free apps and one is the "pro" version of one of the free ones; search slick usb in Google Play.

It does use HOST mode and you can change the baud rate to whatever you need.

Comment: unfortunately the link is dead