# Communicating with serial USB device over Android

Tags: android, serial-port, ftdi, usb-otg

I have one custom made device for measuring current. This device can be connected to PC and communication is done over USB. It is based on FTDI chip. I have application written in Java and that application is using rxtxSerial.dll library and gnu.io.rxtx_2.1.7.4.jar. Now I want to port this application on my android device and I'm litte bit confused what to do that? All I have is android tablet (os version 4.1.1), OTG cable and this measuring device.

Should my device be rooted? Is there any kind of library that I can simply add to my Java Android application and read data over USB? Where to start?

I have tried to port existing application for PC using same library, but rxtxSerial.dll is missing and I can't transfer it to my android device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android USB host-to-serial connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928306/android-usb-host-to-serial-connection)

Answer (score 18):

I can really recommend the USB-Serial-For-Android library, it supports multiple popular usb-to-serial chips (also FTDI) and there is no rooting required. Check out the GitHub project [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android).

Comment: Note that USB-Serial-For-Android library is LGPL.

Answer (score 5):

There is a project dedicated to serial communication on Android. [android-serialport-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/wiki/android_to_rs232_guideline). I think, it is a good resource to start with.

FTDI also provides Android related [resources](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm).

Comment: Just to add, I believe the serialport-api link mentioned requires the device to be rooted to access the USB port.  The FTDI application however doesn't, so I would vote for that.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's currently only one properly maintained library for serial USB communication and it's [felHR85/UsbSerial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial). It supports several USB chips including FTDI (see [Devices Supported](http://mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)).

Unfortunately [mik3y/usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) seems to be dead.

And no, you don't need to root your device for connecting to and communicating with a USB device.

**EDIT:** We have a maintained fork of mik3y's library. See [kai-morich/usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/kai-morich/usb-serial-for-android)

**EDIT2:** It seems that all of these libraries are maintained again, mik3y joined forces with kai-morich and they are working together.