# Running Java program with a trigger sent on USB

Tags: java, android, usb

I would like to use a microUSB port to receive trigger signals and for each trigger a part of a code should start. I don't know if it is possible to do if the +5V source would receive the trigger (see USB specifications here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Pinouts ). So the trigger would be the change from 0V to 5V. Is it possible, or this pin is on +5V level constantly, provided by the computer/tablet/phone? Or is it easier to achieve all this on the Data pins?

Comment: By default an app can only access the data available via Android API and may be some data provided by the sysfs file-system (a lot of them require root permissions). I am not sure but I doubt that your "trigger" is accessible through that API.

Comment: You can use an USB-2-serial OTG connector (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800932/comunicating-with-serial-usb-device-over-android)). Alternatively some people misuse the analog headphone/microphone jacket as input device...

Comment: Ah yeah but sorry, my mistake, the final result is still USB which is apparently not accessible :/

Comment: Maybe using this? What do you think? Or is it purely for devices that are precisely designed for Android use? 

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html