# Communication between an android device and non android smart TV over single RS232 cable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there any way to make a communication between a peripheral with android OS with RS232 support and a non android smart TV with RS232 support? Basically, I have to create an app which will be installed on the android based peripheral so that when it is connected to the TV using single RS232 cable, commands could be sent from peripheral to TV.

I have not been able to proceed because I am unable to find a process for that.

Comment: Is the Android device that is supposed to run the app a stock Android device using a USB to serial connector or does it have customizations for RS232 serial?

Comment: Basically, it has to be customized for RS232. But, in case we don't find a way to establish a connection and there is a way to make it work with USB to RS232 then also it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, in stock Android unless you are doing something special in NDK (C code) with specific hardware there isn't a serial connector.

[Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/index.html) has a [UART](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) but that is specific to Android Things hardware.

If you are trying to get a off-the shelf phone/tablet to connect via serial, a USB-serial dongle would probably be the quickest route.
See: [Communicating with serial USB device over Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21800932/295004)

Since the microUSB connector will be occupied you can run adb over Wifi. See: [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893953/295004)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The device manufacturer will be providing the serial connector in the device. I just have to establish the connection and send commands.