# USB serial communication between ionic and raspberry PI 3

Tags: ionic-framework, raspberry-pi, ionic3, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi-zero

I want USB serial communication between ionic app and raspberry PI 3. I have searched a lot but as both are working as master, not getting any way for this implementation. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

- "Communicating with serial USB device over Android" is not solving my issue. As I am not able to find PID and VID of raspberry pi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating with serial USB device over Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800932/communicating-with-serial-usb-device-over-android)

Comment: To establish this connection need VID and PID of connected device, but I am not finding the way to get VID and PID of raspberry pi. And for ionic serial communication, this is already available [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/serial/]

Comment: I have achieved USB communication between ionic and pi through TCP socket connection. For this only, you need to enable USB tethering in mobile.