# Live video over USB on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, video-streaming, android-camera

Is it possible to send video, not a screen recording of the preview screen, but actual post-processed video data, over USB on Android?  I want to use phones capable of 120/240fps to send that data to a computer to be used as a data stream, not necessarily written to file.

Comment: did you find any news?

Comment: not a whole lot of existing tools, but it can be done with some pretty in depth android development.  this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800932/communicating-with-serial-usb-device-over-android